# State is always undefined in nextjs useReducer and useContext

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context, use-context, use-reducer

I am using context api in my nextjs project but whenever i am trying to get value from state using context api it is always throwing error "undefined"

AppReducer.js

```js
const initialState = {
    isMobile: false,
    user: {},
};

export const AppReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "init_stored": {
            return action.value;
        }
        case "setMobile": {
            return {
                ...state,
                isMobile: (typeof window !== "undefined") && window.innerWidth <= 768,
            };
        }
        case "setUser": {
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload,
            };
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
};
```

AppContext.js

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useReducer } from "react";
import { AppReducer, initialState } from "./AppReducer";

const AppContext = createContext();

export function AppWrapper({ children }) {
    const { state, dispatch } = useReducer(AppReducer);
    console.log("AppWrapper: state", state);

    const contextValue = useMemo(() => {
        return { state, dispatch };
    }, [state, dispatch]);

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
    );
}

export function useAppContext() {
    return useContext(AppContext);
}
```

_app.js

```js
import { AppWrapper } from 'context/AppContext'
import Layout from '@/components/layout'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   return (
      <AppWrapper>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </AppWrapper>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

I am trying to access it inside my homepage like this

```js
 const { state } = useAppContext();
    console.log(state, 'state');
```

Please help what wrong i am doing or anything i am missing here ?

Comment: Use this ```const AppContext = createContext({})```

Comment: Thanks @VidaHedayati but error is still there

Answer (score 1):

Finally found). Use [] not {}

```js
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, { initialState: 'test'});
```

And call state in Home page

```js
const state = useAppContext()
```

Comment: Thanks @VugarTaghiyev but still same error is there

Comment: @HaryanviDeveloper I edited. Send initialState when use useReducer

Comment: @HaryanviDeveloper and your initialState is not exported from appReducer but you are trying to import it

Comment: I am already assigning it to state in AppReducer.js

Comment: @HaryanviDeveloper I think Since you don't use dispatch, it doesn't make that assignment at first.

Comment: @HaryanviDeveloper what was it?

Comment: i have used `export const initialState = {
    isMobile: false,
    user: null,
};`  then assigned it to state={initialState} in AppReducer

Comment: also i used it `useReducer(AppReducer, { initialState})`

Comment: @HaryanviDeveloper great

Answer (score 0):

Please use this way

```
mport { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useReducer } from "react";
import { AppReducer, initialState } from "./AppReducer";

const AppContext = createContext({});

export function AppWrapper({ children }) {
    const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(AppReducer);
    console.log("AppWrapper: state", state);


    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
    );
}

export function useAppContext() {
    return useContext(AppContext);
}
```

Comment: Still error is there @VidaHedayati